# Using the #define macro to standardize class declaration

Tags: c++, class, c-preprocessor

I'm building a C++ DLL for one of my projects. I am trying to standardize the way that are class are defined. So instead of each time writing:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) ClassName
```

I'm building a `#define` macro to ease this process:

```
#define CLASS( cName ) class __declspec(dllexport) cName
```

But, when I'm using it, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Expected a ';'
```

I know you can use a `#define` macro to define an entire class creation, but can it be used to define only the "class header" ?

Thanks,

Keep in mind that I'm trying to do so because we are going to deal with hundreds of classes, so these kinds of "automation" would be most helpful :)

EDIT:

example:

```
#define CLASS( nClass ) class __declspec(dllexport) nClass

CLASS( APTest )
{                        // Here is the error of missing ';'
public:
    APTest();
};
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error before or after the macro call. Can't tell what exactly without seeing more context.

Comment: can you show an example of how you are using this `CLASS` macro? Perhaps it is a simple usage error?

Comment: Can you show the code just above this usage?

Comment: And what comes before the `#define` in that file? If nothing, what comes before wherever that file is included in other files?

Comment: If you are using gcc, try to run it with the option -E, it will show you how compiler is seeing your code, after the preprocessor

Comment: You are sure you don't have any spaces between `CLASS` and `(` in the `#define`?

Comment: This is a pretty standard trap.  The problem isn't related to your macro at all, it is a #include *before* this code for a .h file that's missing a semicolon.

Comment: There is no include before this, this is all the content of my .h file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't do this.

C++ has already been standardized!

If you ever expect other people to read your code then just write it in conventional C++, not some homecooked dialect that looks different.  Get used to the proper C++ syntax, it will make it easier to read other people's C++ code.

One thing that does make sense is to simplify the `__declspec` part, which you can do like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define DLLEXPORT
#endif

class DLLEXPORT APTest
{
    // ...
};
```

You're really not making your life any simpler by writing `CLASS( APTest )` and you make it harder for others to understand. Just say no.

Comment: Hmm... actually makes a lot of sense. I was actually trying to simplify this __declspec(dllexport) command. Thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way than @Wakely. Do it like this:

```
#ifdef MYLIB_DLL

#ifndef MYLIB_IFACE
#ifdef MYLIB_IFACE_EXPORT
#define MYLIB_IFACE _declspec( dllexport )
#else  // !MYLIB_IFACE_EXPORT
#define MYLIB_IFACE _declspec( dllimport )
#endif // !MYLIB_IFACE_EXPORT
#endif // !MYLIB_IFACE

#else  // !MYLIB_DLL

#ifndef MYLIB_IFACE
#define MYLIB_IFACE
#endif // !MYLIB_IFACE
```

Put a block like that in a header that is used by every file in your dll, and in the public header for your dll.

Every symbol that should be exported from your dll gets tagged like this:

```
class MYLIB_IFACE MyClass 
{
};

void MYLIB_IFACE myFunc();
```

Then in every .cpp file in your dll the first line should be:

```
#define MYLIB_IFACE_EXPORT
```

If you do this, then it will build just fine on POSIX systems that don't use dllexport/dllimport. To build a dll version of your lib you define MYLIB_DLL. ( you can do this in the compiler's flags so it can be controlled from your build system )

To build a static version of your lib, don't define MYLIB_DLL.

@Update:

You can extend this to support GCC visilibity like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define KX_SYMBOL_EXPORT _declspec( dllexport )
#define KX_SYMBOL_IMPORT _declspec( dllimport )
#else // GCC
#define KX_SYMBOL_EXPORT __attribute__(( visibility ("default")))
#define KX_SYMBOL_IMPORT 
#endif

#ifdef KX_DLL

#ifndef KX_IFACE
#ifdef KX_IFACE_EXPORT
#define KX_IFACE KX_SYMBOL_EXPORT
#else  // !KX_IFACE_EXPORT
#define KX_IFACE KX_SYMBOL_IMPORT
#endif // !KX_IFACE_EXPORT
#endif // !KX_IFACE

#else  // !KX_DLL

#ifndef KX_IFACE
#define KX_IFACE
#endif // !KX_IFACE

#endif // !KX_DLL
```

I remove the GCC bit in the first example for simplicity. But this is how a really do it. @Wakely is so right.

Comment: Should `MYLIB_DLL_EXPORT` be `MYLIB_IFACE_EXPORT` or vice versa?  For added goodness use GCC's [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) attributes to achieve similar effects on some POSIX platforms

Comment: So astute. Yes for added GCC goodness you SHOULD use the visibility attribute. I clipped that from my production code for simplicity here. And right again about MYLIB_DLL_EXPORT. Fixed.